# Ambiguous use of [sdi]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[With 52 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdi), the [sdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdi) tag is not a very popular one on StackOverflow but there's quite a lot of ambiguity in how it's used. I've skimmed through the list of questions using this tag and I can see the one tag used to describe at least three different subjects:

- Sling Dynamic Includes
- Single Document Interface
- Serial Digital Interface

This is somewhat frustrating for those who happen to be searching for questions on one of these subjects. It's not difficult to weed out the irrelevant results by looking at the other tags used but it takes some time.

What would be the preferred course of action to improve this situation? Should this be split into multiple tags?